# Compare Nested Enums

Tags: swift, enums

If I have

```
var currentState: TransformState = .Default
enum TransformState {
    case Default
    case Error(ErrorState)

    enum ErrorState {
        case Custom
        case Default
    }
}

var state = TransformState.Error(.Custom)
```

How can I check if `state == currentState`?

Comment: Override `==` for your enum.  Possible duplicate of [How to test equality of Swift enums with associated values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24339807/how-to-test-equality-of-swift-enums-with-associated-values)

Comment: @JAL I saw that question and I was still confused because in my case it is nested enums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to implement `Equatable` for `TransformState`

`TransformState.ErrorState` gets it for free, so you can use that fact in your implementations:

```
extension TransformState: Equatable {}
func ==(lhs: TransformState, rhs: TransformState) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.Default, .Default):
        return true

    case let (.Error(lhsErrorState), .Error(rhsErrorState)):
        return lhsErrorState == rhsErrorState

    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Note that in Swift 3.0, you'll be able to put the operator overload inside the extension's body.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is very similar to [the thread shown by JAL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31935209/6541007), because your nest enum `TransformState. ErrorState` is Equatable.

You can write your own `==` like:

```
func == (lhs: TransformState, rhs: TransformState) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.Default, .Default):
        return true
    case (.Error(let state1), .Error(let state2)):
        return state1 == state2
    default:
        return false
    }
}
var currentState: TransformState = .Default

var state = TransformState.Error(.Custom)

print(state == currentState) //->false

currentState = .Error(.Custom)
print(state == currentState) //->true
```

Answer (score 1):

Override `==` for your enum.

```
func ==(lhs: TransformState, rhs: TransformState) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.Default, .Default):
        return true

    case (.Error(.Custom), .Error(.Custom)):
        return true

    case (.Error(.Default), .Error(.Default)):
        return true

    default:
        return false
    }
}
```