# Compact code to check enum and its associated value

Tags: swift, enums

I have two enums:

```
enum Bar {
    case bar1
    case bar2
}

enum Foo {
    case foo1
    case foo2(bar: Bar)
}
```

and a variable:

```
var v: Foo = ...
```

Now I want to check if `v` is of `foo2` type, and moreover its associated value is `bar2`:

```
// if v is foo2_bar2 I print "ok"

switch v {
case .foo2(let type):
    if type == .bar2 {
        print("ok")
    }
default:
    break
}
```

It works, but takes 8 code lines which is too much for such a simple check I guess.
Is there any more compact form?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54926767/1187415: With `enum Foo: Equatable { .. }` you can simply compare `if v == .foo2(bar: .bar2) { .. }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same thing like this:

```
let x: Foo = .foo2(bar: .bar2)

if case let .foo2(bar) = x, bar == .bar2 {
    print("ok")
}
```